# How to install KVM to use existing installed OS's?

Tags: kvm

I have four partitions on 2 HD's, sda and sdb, each having Debian installed in different configurations. My general purpose OS is on sda1, and I want to be able to run VM's of the other OS's while logged in to sda1.

A recommendation I got was to use KVM since it apparently allows use of an existing installed OS as it's 'image'.

I have never used KVM before and would appreciate guidelines & references on how to go about doing install and setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot you other systems like this:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /dev/sdb -m 2G -enable-kvm  \
    -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 -net nic
```

Assuming that `/dev/sdb` has a working grub installation.

The `-net` enables simple networking support (TCP/UDP but no ICMP) and creates a port redirection for ssh (you can then connect to local port 10022 on the host to ssh into the VM). With `-m 2G` you assign 2GB RAM to this KVM instance.

Comment: precisely what I wanted :) - my /home's for the guests are on different drive/part so I needed to add `-drive file=/dev/sdx` after the -hda /..; also am using grub-menu from sda to load guests. Nice to see the guest GUI in a window! thx (just as an aside: the man page for qemu-system-x86_64 is a mission ;)

Answer (score 0):

KVM is a hypervisor in the Linux Kernel.

You are likely looking for a GUI front-end such as [GNOME Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes) or  [Virtual Machine Manager](http://virt-manager.org/).

Most GUI front-ends use qemu behind the hood. Qemu will make use of the kernel's KVM support if available.

Resources:

- [Wikipedia: Kernel-based Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine)
- [KVM Project Page](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page)